# \ref{} results in ??? in Typora Latex

Tags: markdown, mathjax

I am using Typora as markdown editor for writing math equations.  I am running into a problem where  eg `\ref{eqn:dnj}` results in `???` when cross referencing to `\label{eqn:dnj}`.

Here is an extract from the text:

```
$$
\begin{split} \label{eqn:dnj}
\delta_{n_j}&= i_a-i_{s_j} \\
\therefore\quad i_{s_j}&=i_a-\delta_{n_j}
\end{split}
$$
```

followed by the cross reference:

```
If $\delta_{n_{j^{\prime}}} \lt i_{s_j}$ it follows from $\ref{eqn:dnj}$
```

This results in the output:

`... it follows from ???`

Using the same in a pure LaTeX editor renders correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further investigation:

It would appear that the issue is that the `\label{eqn:dnj}` appears inside the `\begin{split}...\end{split}` block.

The following implementation solves the problem:

```
$$
\label{eqn:dnj} 
\begin{split}
\delta_{n_j}= i_a-i_{s_j} \\
\therefore\quad i_{s_j}=i_a-\delta_{n_j}
\end{split}
$$
```

Comment: But if you use `\begin{align}...\end{align}` then `label` must be inside the block.